# Saving core data objects in HTTP response

Tags: ios, core-data

Consider the following piece of code which is a simple request to get user data for a particular username.

```
- (void)updateInformation
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *httpManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": self.username};
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = <create_op>

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response){
        // use response to populate user
        // self.fullname = response[@"fullname"];
    }failure:nil];

    [httpManager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

This code is part of a category for a particular entity for e.g. `User`.

Now usually this method is called in a `scheduleBlock`. `scheduleBlock` (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/XMPPFramework/3.6.1/Classes/XMPPCoreDataStorage.html#//api/name/scheduleBlock:):

> This method asynchronously invokes the given block (dispatch_async) on the storageQueue.

Now my question is simple — the request response is received in a different thread as compared to the `storageQueue` on which the `updateInformation` method is actually called => there needs to be a different managed object context that needs to be created to store the object and then sync those changes with the context for the storage queue. *Is this right?*

Another question is — is there a better way of handling this, i.e. not creating a new context and trying to sync it with the storage queue context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same context but since you are coming in from another thread/queue then you will need to wrap the Core Data processing code in a `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` so that the processing is done on the correct thread that is associated with the context.

Comment: The issue is that the defined managed object context in the code linked above uses the `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` concurrency type (for the background/storage moc). Therefore, performBlock cannot be used.

Comment: Well I have changed the concurrency type to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. I am not sure if its going to have any repercussions (not an expert in core data).

Comment: `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is going away in 9 anyway so best to change it. You can also turn on the concurrency debug flag and confirm that you are not running into any other threading issues.